# What frameworks are good for a beginner in automated functional testing?

Tags: automated-testing, python, ruby

I want to start doing some functional testing.  I tried some time ago in Java and Selenium, but seemed to run into a number of problems with configuration.
Previously I have made simple tests with Robot Framework and Python.

Now I am considering both Python or Ruby. Do you recommend some tools and language with detailed tutorials.  Are there low cost books or tutorials available?

I'd like to start with a framework that required a minimum of configuration to get started

Would Python and the Robot Framework is good?
Would sikuli be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern web frameworks require little to no configuration to get started for local learning and testing.  To adapt them to particular environments, databases, OS's, etc. they need to be configured correctly, hence configuration files and settings.

For example with Ruby, Ruby on Rails, RSpec and Capybara you can create a new application with rails new app_name and then starting writing UI feature tests with RSpec and (for UI tests) Capybara tests).  Search for links, tutorials and tools for Capybara

Similarly Python has django and I believe it is similarly easy to get started if you focus your search on that.

Of coure you don't need to create your own application.
You could use those frameworks and for subject you could pick something as simple as google searches that you automate, e.g. use RSpec and Capybara against google searches and not create a Ruby on Rails application.  Search for capybara without rails.  I found https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/how-to-seutp-capybara-with-rspec-no-rails/ which seemed relatively recent (2 years) compared to several 5 years old (ancient in RoR terms) examples.

Generally I recommend [Code School](http://codeschool.com), [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com)
If you go down the Ruby route railscasts.com is great although starting to become a little dated.